# wsdl2java generated code ClassCastException in factory methods

Tags: java, osgi, apache-axis, wsdl2java, xmlbeans

I used the axis2 wsdl2java tool with xmlbeans binding to generate client code for soap calls.  I am running this client in OSGi and as far as I can tell I have all of the necessary bundles needed to run axis2 in OSGi.  Whenever I try to create an instance of one of the generated classes using the [class].Factory.newInstance() method I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlComplexContentImpl cannot be cast to tews6.wsdl.ViewUserSearchTaskContextDocument
at tews6.wsdl.ViewUserSearchTaskContextDocument$Factory.newInstance(ViewUserSearchTaskContextDocument.java:72)
at web.soap.SoapSend.start(SoapSend.java:19)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.felix.dm.InvocationUtil.invokeMethod(InvocationUtil.java:111)
at org.apache.felix.dm.InvocationUtil.invokeCallbackMethod(InvocationUtil.java:66)
at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.ComponentImpl.invokeCallbackMethod(ComponentImpl.java:688)
at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.ComponentImpl.invoke(ComponentImpl.java:679)
at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.ComponentImpl.bindService(ComponentImpl.java:624)
at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.ComponentImpl.access$400(ComponentImpl.java:52)
at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.ComponentImpl$7.run(ComponentImpl.java:181)
at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.SerialExecutor$1.run(SerialExecutor.java:47)
at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.SerialExecutor.scheduleNext(SerialExecutor.java:84)
at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.SerialExecutor.access$000(SerialExecutor.java:33)
at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.SerialExecutor$1.run(SerialExecutor.java:50)
at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.SerialExecutor.scheduleNext(SerialExecutor.java:84)
at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.SerialExecutor.execute(SerialExecutor.java:68)
at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.ComponentImpl.calculateStateChanges(ComponentImpl.java:231)
at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.ComponentImpl.start(ComponentImpl.java:399)
at org.apache.felix.dm.DependencyManager.add(DependencyManager.java:169)
at web.soap.Activator.init(Activator.java:16)
at org.apache.felix.dm.DependencyActivatorBase.start(DependencyActivatorBase.java:76)
at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:645)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2146)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2064)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:955)
at aQute.launcher.Launcher.update(Launcher.java:378)
at aQute.launcher.Launcher$1.run(Launcher.java:176)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have looked around extensively online and have found very little information on this problem.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of axis2 are you using?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this question? I'm hitting the same problem at the moment within the Play framework and online solutions are scarce.

Comment: So it's been a few years, but if I recall, there were additional files created (xml maybe?) other than the java files, and those needed to be included as part of the osgi bundle.  Sorry I can't give more specifics, I honestly don't remember.  Just make sure that everything generated by the wsdl2java tool is accessable to the java code